# In springboot, can I connect with two database so that if one database is giving exception then I can connect to the other database dynamically

Tags: database, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, datasource

Requirement in detail:

So I have two databases (both are in sync) and somehow one goes down and Spring Boot application starts giving exceptions. In this case I want the application to connect to the second database.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the two databases you mentioned, are in sync how ? is it Oracle in Data Guard ?

Comment: This documentation describes client failover best practices, maybe it is helpful to you: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_fcf.htm#HABPT4969

Comment: @RobertoHernandez.. Yes it is data gaurd

Comment: you can use jdbc with TAF. You want me to answer with an example

Comment: @RobertoHernandez.. Yes pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a DataGuard implementation in Oracle with a Primary database and another one in Standby mode, Oracle Transparent Application Failover is the way to go.

> Transparent Application Failover (TAF) is a feature of the Java
> Database Connectivity (JDBC) Oracle Call Interface (OCI) driver. It
> enables the application to automatically reconnect to a database, if
> the database instance to which the connection is made fails. In this
> case, the active transactions roll back.

**Database Setup**

I am assuming your implementation of DG uses Oracle Restart.

Datatase: TESTDB
Service in TAF: TESTDB_HA

**Primary site**

```
srvctl add service -d testdb -s testdb_ha -l PRIMARY -y AUTOMATIC -e select -m BASIC -z 200 -w 1
srvctl start service -d testdb -s testdbha
```

**Standby site**

```
srvctl add service -d testdb -s testdb_ha-l PRIMARY -y AUTOMATIC -e select -m BASIC -z 200 -w 1
srvctl modify service -d testdb -s testdb_ha -failovermethod basic
```

**Your JDBC connection**

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=primaryserver)(protocol=tcp)(port=yourdbport))(address=(host=standbyserver)(protocol=tcp)(port=yourport))(failover=yes)(connect_data=(service_name=testdb_ha)(failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic))))
```

In this setup, in case a failover from Primary to Standby, the connection will keep working once the failover is completed without manual intervention.

I am using this configuration currently in applications store in Kubernetes, using Spring Boot and/or Hibernate, and in normal Jboss Java applications. I have personally tested failover scenarios totally transparent for the applications. Obviously, if you have a transaction or query running in the moment the failover is being performed, you will get an error. But you don't need to manually change any jdbc settings in case of switch from primary site to standby site.

Comment: The JDBC connection you mentioned.. Can you please provide me one example ?

Comment: is in the answer. If this is what you are looking for, please accept the answer. It is the best way to say thank you in StackOverflow

Comment: Can you please provide me one example of jdbc connection .. suppose my details are :

primary ip : 10.32.9.234
other ip : 10.32.9.235

Service name : db_prod

Comment: @AnuragGhosh what is the database port?

Comment: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(host=10.32.9.234)(protocol=tcp)(port=yourdbport))(address=(host=10.32.9.235)(protocol=tcp)(port=yourport))(failover=yes)(connect_data=(service_name=db_prod)(failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic))))`  Replace yourport with the database port you have in your environment

Comment: we have different service names db_prod and db_prod1 for servers... How do we mention those things in the url ? database ports are 1521 (for both)

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description_list=(failover=yes)(description=(address=(host=10.32.11.176)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=dbprod.agnity.com)(failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic))))(description=(address=(host=10.32.11.177)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(service_name=dbprod.agnity.com)(failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic)))))

Comment: I tried the above one.. but if I make primary database down.. it is not able to connect to the second database

Comment: have you check when the failover/switchover is done in Data Guard that the service db_prod is up and enable in the standby site ?

Comment: yes.. that was missing... now it is working fine.. Thank you very much for your help..

Comment: @AnuragGhosh you are very welcome